# TypeScript Missing from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

My TypeScript syntax highlighting has been broken in Visual Studio. When I tried to check my settings in Tools>Options>Text Editor, there's no option for TypeScript. How can I add this back in to fix TypeScript?

Comment: What version of visual studio do you have?

Comment: I'm currently on Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Comment: Strange, I thought that version had typescript built in. Maybe try installing [the plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304).

Comment: It should be built in (since Update 2, I believe) and I've used it before. My guess is that something went wrong, so I'll try installing the plugin and we'll see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [download the latest version from here (1.5 beta)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/107f89a0-a542-4264-b0a9-eb91037cf7af):

Visual Studio updates less often than TypeScript, so although there are a lot of native TypeScript features, you need the extension too.

The extension contains the Visual Studio "TypeScript experience" and also the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem in Visual Studio 2017 and it seems that TypeScript options have been merged with JavaScript ones in this version of Visual Studio.

These options can be found under Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript item.

**Note:** Visual Studio 2015 had a separate item for TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue where the entire menu option was missing (Under "HTML (Web Forms)" there was "JSON" instead of the "Javascript/TypeScript" between them as seen here:

[image]

To Solve this, I ran the Visual Studio Installer and chose "Repair"